# Does Ubuntu detect and recognize Windows phones?

Tags: nokia, windows-phone

I recently bought a Nokia Lumia with Windows Phone 8 OS on it; and now I'm planning to install Ubuntu on my Laptop.

My concern is, does Ubuntu detect or recognize Windows phone?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put: yes this works in Ubuntu.

--

So I have been given a Nokia 520 as a works mobile.

I have a works laptop running Windows 7 and am running Xubuntu Raring in VirtualBox.
As far as I'm aware it's an unupgraded version of Xubuntu so this is good for a freshly downloaded disc.

I actually plugged the device in and told VirtualBox to pass through the USB connection to the VM.

In the file manager (Thunar) I can see the phone appear and when I open it a second root filesystem shows.

On opening this I see the media (piccies/vids/music) appear in a tree.
I can select these files and copy then to a folder in Ubuntu.

So the answer is: this works with Windows Phone 8 in Xubuntu Raring without any extra software.
Probably works in Ubuntu too, but I didn't try that.

I'm quite pleased I don't have to install Zune in Windows or use SkyDrive or summat.

What pleases me the most is not having to set up a Microsoft account and have to agree to share information with Microsoft, just to get my vids and piccies off the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my Windows 7 has a hard time to recognize my Lumia via USB or bluetooth. A sync of Outlook calendar only works with ad-hoc network (need a third party program for that!) and then Akruto (cannot access company's Exchange server), so I'd be very surprised if Ubuntu will work so much better than Microsoft's own products, which are mostly disfunctional for my purposes. The same can be said for OneNote, I`ve even tried manual upload to Skydrive to exchange files, to no avail. 
Getting a Lumia to work with Win 7 is a disaster.